# How do I properly deploy and serve a react micro frontend to minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, webpack, minikube, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm new to kubernetes and wanted to create a proof of concept with micro frontends. I'm trying to deploy my containerised frontend to Minikube, but unfortunately it isn't able to load properly, even though it works perfectly when I run it in docker. See screenshot below.
[image: workingFrontend]

My `deployment.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mf1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mf1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mf1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mf1
          image: furkanrgb/microfrontend1:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
```

My `service.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mf1-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mf1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 31000
```

The react app partially loads, as seen on the screenshot below. The title of the tab correctly shows `mf1`.
[image: Tab]

However, I encounter an error loading the main js files.
[image: errors]

I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to change to make this work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `targetPort` of your service has to match the `containerPort` of your container, i.e. 80.

Comment: I'm a step closer to figuring out what exactly I'm doing wrong. It has to do with the publicPath in the webpack config file. I need to (dynamically) set this to the path it gets on a kubernetes cluster